# Null multiple data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

How Can I null multiple data.frames? I can find my data.frames with this but am stuck to null them.

```
ls(pattern="pqr")
```

I usually did this to nullify any data.frame.

```
abc<-NULL
pqr<-NULL
```

Comment: just remove objects using `rm` if you don't need them anymore. You can combine this with `ls` using something like `rm(list = ls(pattern = "pqr"))`

Comment: There is a condition down in the script if(!is.null(pqr)){do something}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `assign` `NULL` in a for loop. Try out:

```
for (i in seq_along(ls(pattern = "pqr"))){
        assign(ls(pattern = "pqr")[i], NULL)
}
```

Comment: There are approximately 20+ data.frames like abc_pqr, bcd_pqr, pqr_abc,abc_abc. So I am using ls(pattern) to find all pqr, using condition if nrow = 0 and then nullifing if it is 0